# How can i get all TD data upon clicking on a TR with Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am having a table with multiple rows and i want to get all the TD data after clicking on a particular ROW.

My Table is

```
<table>
 <tr class="person">
   <td class="id">1900</td>
   <td class="name">John</td>
   <td class="gender">Male</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="person">
   <td class="id">2000</td>
   <td class="name">Pitt</td>
   <td class="gender">Female</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How can i Get id, name, gender after clicking on Row using Jquery.

```
Ex: If i click on John Row i should get 1900, John, Male and same for Pitt also
```

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution. You may try find() method instead of children()

```
$(function(){
    $('.person').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).children('.id').text();
        var name= $(this).children('.name').text();
        var gender = $(this).children('.gender').text();

        alert('Selected ID: ' + id + ', Name: ' + name + ', Gender: ' + gender);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

To get them separately:

```
var arr = [];
$('#tableID > tbody > tr').click(function(){
  arr = $(this).find('td').map(function(){
     return this.innerHTML;
  }).get();

  arr = arr.split(',');
  var id = arr[0];
  var name = arr[1];
  var gender = arr[2];
});
```

---

You can do:

```
var arr = [];
$('#tableID > tbody > tr').click(function(){
  arr = $(this).find('td').map(function(){
     return this.innerHTML;
  }).get();

  alert(arr);
});
```

### [Check out the DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ogara4/2)

Comment: @Thank You. But i want the fields individually not whole data.

Comment: @KillerFish: Ok check out my answer updated to get them separately :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr").bind("click", function(e){
 var id = $(this).find("td.id").text();
 var name = $(this).find("td.name").text();
 var gender = $(this).find("td.gender").text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(function(){
    $('.person>td').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).parent().children().text());
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and finally solved using this code to get all tr data from the table:

```
$('.tb_add').click(function ()
{
  var table = $("table tbody");
  table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
        r1 = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
        r2 = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
        alert(r1+" "+r2);
 });
 });
```