# How to get data from a table row with a link in each row?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

How to retrieve data from a table row after clicking on the "Edit" link?

This is the table code in javascript

```
var str = "<table style=width:100%; border-spacing:0; id='homeworkTable' class='smallTableVH'>";
            str+= "<form action='javascript:editHomeworkInterface()' name='viewHomeworkF'>";
            str+="<tr>";
            for (var i=0;i<output.ID.length;i++)
            {
                if(output.ID[i]=="Staff_ID")
                {
                }
                else
                str+="<th>"+output.UI_label[i]+"</th>"; //list the column name
            }

            var homeworkInterfaceToBeCreate = 
                { 
                    'output': result
                };




                localStorage.setItem('homeworkInterfaceToBeCreate',JSON.stringify(homeworkInterfaceToBeCreate));//stringify is to change the value to json

            //get data from database 
            for(var i=0;i<output.Data.length;i++)
            {
                str+="<tr>";
                str+="<td>"+output.Data[i][0]+"</td>";
                str+="<td>"+output.Data[i][1]+"</td>";
                str+="<td>"+output.Data[i][2]+"</td>";
                str+="<td>"+output.Data[i][3]+"</td>";
                str+="<td>"+output.Data[i][5]+"</td>";
                str+="<td>";
                str+="<form id='selectedRow'><div class='link'>";
                str+="<a href='javascript:editHomeworkInterface()' id='checkbox_"+i+"'                   class='checkbox' type='button' name='name' value=''>Edit</a>";
                str+="</div></form>";
                str+="</td>";
                str+="</tr>";
            }
            str+= "<input type='hidden' name='totalHomework' id='totalHomework' value='"+output.Data.length+"'>";//hidden field
            str+="</tr>";
            str+="</table>";
```

How can i retrieve the data from the table after clicking on the "Edit" link?

Comment: please go through `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101360/how-can-i-get-all-td-data-upon-clicking-on-a-tr-with-jquery` this post.

Comment: @AtulNar i am using javascript instead of jquery, hope to get solution using javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something link this:

Change this

```
str+="<a href='javascript:editHomeworkInterface()' id='checkbox_"+i+"'                   class='checkbox' type='button' name='name' value=''>Edit</a>"
```

to

```
str+="<a class='alink' href='javascript:void(0)'>Edit</a>"
```

Javascript :

```
$('.alink').click(function() {
   var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
  str += "Homework ID : <input type='text' class='textbox' id='id_" + count + "' readonly='readonly' value='" + row.cells[0].innerHTML + "'/>";
  str += "Homework Description : <textarea rows='8' cols='50' name='name' class='textarea' id='description_" + count + "'>" + row.cells[1].innerHTML + "</textarea>";
});
```

Comment: Before this i am using checkbox to check multiple row from the table and click on a button to get the selected row data, but now i want replace the checkbox with a link name "Edit" which only can get the particular row after i clicked on the link at the particular row.

Comment: this is the code of editHomeworkInterface
    var str= "<form action='javascript:updateHomework()' name='homeworkF'><div class='input-box'>";
for(var j=0; j<output1.Data.length; j++)
    {
     document.getElementById("checkbox_"+j).clicked;
if(document.getElementById("checkbox_"+j).clicked)
{
str+= "Homework ID : <input type='text' class='textbox' id='id_"+count+"' readonly='readonly' value='"+output1.Data[j][0]+"'/>";

str+= "Homework Description : <textarea rows='8' cols='50' name='name' class='textarea' id='description_"+count+"'>"+output1.Data[j][1]+"</textarea>";
  ...
count++;}

Comment: @Kevin Foong: Ok i have update the code, now there will be a edit link instead of checkbox, and it will read data from parent tr on click.

Comment: is it possible if use something like document.getElementById to get the particular row link after it was clicked? and how to do that?

Comment: you will need to make sure that jQuery js is included <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> in head before our code.

Comment: error is still there. i am sorry because i am just a beginner and have no idea about jquery. Perhaps can i email you my coding?